# PHP OCI8 Extention Wont Load After Reboot

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I'm getting the below error in the logs after a reboot, prior to the reboot everything was working perfectly. It's running on a Win 2008 server.

I've tried absolutely everything but just can't figure out what's going on, any help greatly appreciated?!

> [Fri Nov 08 11:07:06.787392 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4916:tid 616] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1704
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/ext/php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I've outlined it below.

If you've installed any other Oracle software on the same server, the instant client path has to be the first path in the environment PATH variable otherwise the OCI8 extension will use ORACLE_HOME as it is set by the first Oracle path it finds in the environment PATH variable.

You will need to reboot the machine after this to allow for PHP to pick-up the path changes.